# "unavailable"(Offline) presence not updating at the both end

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

i used `- (void)blockJID:(XMPPJID*)xmppJID` method in  `XMPPBlocking` class

```
<iq from='juliet@capulet.com/chamber' type='set' id='block1'>
      <block xmlns='urn:xmpp:blocking'>
         <item jid='romeo@montague.net'/>
      </block>
    </iq>
```

I want to block user(s) in a xmpp application (like whatsapp). when i use the above code, "unavailable" presence not updating at the both end. but after re-connecting, it updating "unavailable" presence at the both end.

when i block user, my requirements are,

- user should not receive messages at both end (it works perfectly not even reconnected)
- both user should be "unavailable" (the other end not receiving anything when i execute above IQ, So working only after reconnected)

How can i notify offline presence each other after blocking? 
How can i achieve this in proper way?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i done with.

For notify buddy(other end user) used below code,

```
XMPPPresence *presence = [[XMPPPresence alloc] initWithType:@"unavailable" to:jid]; 
[_xmppStream sendElement:presence];
```

And buddy's presence updated locally in sender side.

For unblock case, i just subscribe buddy(other end user) again.

I don't know whether its correct way. i always waiting for perfect solutions from you all.

Comment: Why not revoke the presence subscription if you want to block someone?

Comment: Yeah. i tried, but if i do like that what i need to do when i unblock?

Comment: Didn't know that you need to unblock.  Check `Blocking Communication` https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#privacy